# Google Earth/KML placemark balloon with a link that can play the tour it is contained within

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am working with Google Earth (not plugin) and would like to find out if there is a way to Play a tour that is already loaded in the TOC from a placemark's balloon.  This placemark is actually part of the kmz that also contains the tour.  Is there a way to reference the Tour by Id and tell Google Earth to play it?  Thinking something like `< a href=GE.Play(tourID) >`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with the standalone client. with the plugin it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-tour capability in KML had been requested as far back as 2009.

http://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/issues/detail?id=248

Likewise, this has been discussed in the Google Earth and KML forums:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/kml-support-advanced/j_DQhNwNR7E

This is not yet directly supported in raw KML and Google Earth client. Using the Google Earth API you could automatically play a tour but it would be nice to do this directly with KML and Google Earth.

Google supports [KML extensions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions) through the gx: namespace. Maybe if enough users ask for this feature it can be added to a future release of Google Earth.